# What is the AOSP Toolchain?

Tags: java, android, android-source, mobile-development

I'm looking to build some kernel source code, and I keep seeing "AOSP Toolchain". I know that AOSP is the Android Open Source Project, but I'm wondering what exactly is the "toolchain"?

Comment: Are you talking about: https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html#downloading-a-prebuilt-gcc?

Answer (score 2):

The AOSP toolchain is, essentially, the collection of tools used to build Android.

The [documentation](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) [describes](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) how to set up a suitable toolchain.  It normally happens automatically when you try to build anything for your target.  This build normally happens by invoking the `lunch` command.

Comment: So this isn't included in the standard SDK?

Comment: No.  The Android SDK is made for application developers.  You will have a very bad time trying to build any part of AOSP with the developer SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The toolchain (even in the broader sense, not just AOSP) is the set of tools necessary to build software and firmware for a specific platform.  In the sense of AOSP, this includes all the scripts and binaries necessary to interpret and build Android make files, scripts necessary for selecting architectures, for inspecting source code, for running tests on a build, etc.

Basically the toolchain is everything you need to develop for a platform.

Answer (score 0):

For readers who saw `get the proper toolchain packages from AOSP or CodeSourcery or ETC` and wanted to know where to get it -

It's not clearly mentioned In the Android source website itself what these tools are specifically. you have to download the entire repo and you will find it inside.